# Wait for Python to finish before next loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, process, wait

I've tried a few different methods, even just raw wait(240) but it appears that this sometimes doesnt even given enough time.

However I can not get these 2 lines to return before it loops into the next for.

```
    f.summary()
    f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from fitter import Fitter#, get_common_distributions, get_distributions
from fitter import get_common_distributions

from fitter import get_distributions

from IPython.display import clear_output
import warnings
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.common import SettingWithCopyWarning
warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=SettingWithCopyWarning)

import time
import subprocess

dataset = pd.read_csv("econ.csv")

for col in dataset.columns:
    try:
        print(col)
        
        spac = dataset[col].values
        f = Fitter(spac, distributions=get_distributions())
        f.fit()
        f.summary()
        f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')
        print("")
        #subprocess.call
        
        #result = col.result
        #time.sleep(180)
        
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What do you mean return? Those lines are not return statements, or assigned to a variable. Is it possible an exception is being raised someplace? You are allowing all exceptions in the try block to be passed (generally bad practice), and don't seem to be logging/printing them. At the very least,
```except Exception as e:  print(e)```

Comment: For example:

f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')

Will return the follow output in the Juypter Notebook -
{'norminvgauss': {'a': 1.8757452743604515,
  'b': -0.658767997246611,
  'loc': 0.4690289128911632,
  'scale': 1.2460938937235269}}

Comment: It's possible in the jupyter notebook, if `f.get_best(...)` is not the last line in the cell, nothing will be printed. Can you maybe verify if that's true or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes @crunker99, you are correct, the notebook does appear to be jumping on because of the f.get_best(...) not being the last line.

As such I set up an empty dataframe and captured the outputs as such.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': pd.Series([], dtype='str'),
                   'Output': pd.Series([], dtype='str')})

df.loc[n]=[col]+[f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')]
```

Cheers! A bit silly on my side! haha